# Centos6 - Apache | Subdomains Not Working

Tags: apache, dns, centos, subdomain

Ok, so I'm having some trouble with apache on my CentOS 6 (64bit) Webserver.

Whenever I load http://myserver.com/sub, it works perfectly and loads the page in /var/www/html/sub.

For some reason, when loading http://sub.myserver.com, it loads the page in `/var/www/html`, rather than `/var/www/html/sub`.

Also, my DNS name servers are ran on the same vps. Here are the records in the zone file:

```
; Mapping

@               IN  A               127.0.0.1
www             IN  A               127.0.0.1
```

Is there a problem with my setup or do I need to edit some configurations?

Thanks.

Comment: This is going to be an issue with your apache configuration, it would probably help if you can post some of your apache config (its not a DNS issue because the request is hitting the server)

Comment: @MichaelB what would I need to be changing?

Comment: Unfortunately it has been quite a while since I've done anything with Apache, I'd need to poke around and kick it a few times to remember how to do that! But if you can post the config relating to your sub domain I'm sure someone more able will answer

Answer (score 0):

On my server, I have set a virtual host to get subdomains to work. I believe that apache doesn't know where to send the subdomain.domain.tld request if you don't have the virtual host set up for it so it just sends it to the same place as primarydomainl.tld requests are going.

You have to set up virtual hosts in your apache configuration files. There are several way to do it, but I personally decided to just put it into the httpd.conf file.

If you're on centos then it will be in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
On ubuntu it's in /etc/apache2/ somewhere, though I'm not completely sure of the whole path and don't have an ubuntu machine spun up atm to check.

Here's an example of what's currently working properly on my server:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName primarydomain.tld
        ServerAlias www.primarydomain.tld
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        <Directory "/var/www/html">
                allow from all
                Options +Indexes
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>    

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName      subdomain.primarydomain.tld
        DocumentRoot    /var/www/subdomain
        <Directory "/var/www/subdomain">
                allow from all
                Options +Indexes
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

You'll also need to make sure you have A and CNAME records setup:

A subdomain.primarydomain.tld ipaddress
CNAME *.subdomain.primarydomain.tld subdomain.primarydomain.tld